# How to address Learndash Focus Mode with a shortcode

Tags: wordpress

how do i call an alien shortcode ONLY if user is logged in and in Learndash focus mode?

My problem is in the "is focus mode" part.

```
<?php $user = wp_get_current_user();
**if focus mode and** ( in_array('subscriber', (array) $user->roles )) {
do_shortcode("[doSomethingNice]");
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

found it, very easy. just edit the theme in lms ->themes ->ld30 -> templates -> focus